# How to avoid overwriting column (multiple condition statements that flag a column) pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to update a list of columns to appropriate datatypes. There are 1500 columns but a lot of them are repeats. I am trying to write a script where I could just say something like 'Key' and 'claim' as BIGINT, while anything that ends in DT should be a date and 'name' should be VARCHAR.

The code below identifies the rows appropriately, but only when you run it individually. So how can you combine into one so that the last line doesn't overwrite the previous ones.

Here is my df and code thus far:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnTitles': ['Key', 'Claim', 'First_dt', 'Second_dt', 'Third_dt','name','Claim', 'Key'], 
               'CurrentDataTypes': ['String','String','String','String','String','String','String','String']})

bigint = ['Key','Claim']
bigint = ['name']
df['Updated'] = df[df['ColumnTitles'].isin(bigint)]
df['Updated'] = df[df['ColumnTitles'].isin(bigint)]
df['Updated'] = np.where(df['ColumnTitles'].str.contains("_dt", case=False, na=False), 'Date', '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see the correlation between your question and the link, and here is a solution

```
bigint = ['Key','Claim']
df.loc[df['ColumnTitles'].isin(bigint),'Updatee']='bigint'
bigint = ['name']
df.loc[df['ColumnTitles'].isin(bigint),'Updatee']='VARCHAR'
df=df.fillna('Date')
df
Out[385]: 
  ColumnTitles CurrentDataTypes  Updatee
0          Key           String   bigint
1        Claim           String   bigint
2     First_dt           String     Date
3    Second_dt           String     Date
4     Third_dt           String     Date
5         name           String  VARCHAR
6        Claim           String   bigint
7          Key           String   bigint
```